# Lifting electromagnet & Induced EMF

Tags: electromagnetism

An electromagnet is lifting/pulling large pieces of iron, from a distance $r$.
Is there an induced **EMF** in the coils of the electromagnet due to the change in flux?

Another configuration would be the piece of iron is rotating around the electromagnet is there still **EMF** induced?

I'm confused because if a ferromagnet is introduced to a magnetic field, there is  a change if flux, however, is the magnetic field produced by the ferromagnet = to the external magnetic field? 
Also are there large voltages induced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time there's a change in the flux in the coil for whatever reason there will be an induced EMF in the coils.

Comment: In this case, how is there change? Increase in flux or... & That change is equal to -N delta(BA)/delta (t)?